# Users who have received a badge for a particular tag

Tags: discussion, support, badges, tag-badges

I was wondering where in Stack Overflow you can find a list of users who have received a badge for particular tag say C# or ASP.Net etc. ? Sorry if its obvious but I couldn't find it.

EDIT: Sorry I meant had got a badge tag I.e. gold for a 1000 up votest that type of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browse to the [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page and then select the [tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) (on the far right of the page) and then select the tag you're interested in.

If you already have the badge yourself you can also select the badge from your profile page and it will take you straight to the page.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was very clear. I meant a list of people who have got a tag-badge.

Comment: @Aim Kai - I've reworded the answer to make it clearer.